# multiple JS form submit on change inside a PHP while

Tags: javascript, php

I have a while in PHP that is building a table.  Inside my while, I have a dropdown menu that I want to execute code on change....  The form submit on change doesn'T work... 
This is my code:

```
<?
while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array( $data)) 
{  ?>

<form name="FormSize" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" > 
  <td>
  <select name="size[]"  class="form-field3" OnChange="document.FormSize.submit();" >

      <? foreach ($sizearray as $value) {  ?>
      <option value="$value" <? if($data2['size'] == $value) { echo "selected";} ?> ><?     echo $value; ?></option>
      <? } ?>

  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<? echo $data2['product_id']; ?>">
 </td>
</form>

<? } ?>
```

and on top of my page, I have this to execute the code..

```
<? 
//submit size form
if (isset($_POST['size'])) 
{   
foreach($_POST['product_id'] as $key => $id)
{
    $product_id = $id;
    $newsize = $_POST['size'][$key];
    $sql3 = mysql_query("update cart SET size = '".$newsize."' where product_id = '".$product_id."' ");                         
}
?>
```

any idea why it's not executing ?

Comment: my form name is unique... and I have put the form tag inside tr before and it worked... I'm not sure that's the issue

Comment: No, you are generating multiple forms with the same nam in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple forms with the same `name="FormSize"`. So `document.FormSize` will be an array-like object, and you need to access the appropriate one. You can do this by using `this.form` to refer to the `<form>` that contains the `<select>`.

You also need to fix the element nesting -- the `<form>` has to be inside the `<td>`, not the other way around.

```
<?
while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array( $data)) 
{  ?>

<td>
  <form name="FormSize" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" > 
  <select name="size[]"  class="form-field3" OnChange="this.form.submit();" >

      <? foreach ($sizearray as $value) {  ?>
      <option value="$value" <? if($data2['size'] == $value) { echo "selected";} ?> ><?     echo $value; ?></option>
      <? } ?>

  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<? echo $data2['product_id']; ?>">
  </form>
/td>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be because the html is not valid, you cannot put your `form` tag as a direct child of a `tr`.

Apart from that, naming all your forms the same will make it pretty hard to submit a specific one by its name.

As you are using arrays for your `input` names, I assume that you mean all of them to be in the same form, so you should just have your form wrap the table and take it out of the `while` loop.